# The telegram bot does not delete stickers from the group

Tags: python, filter, python-telegram-bot

I create a telegram bot using the Python-Telegram-Bot framework and the Re Module.
The bot should delete the stickers the members send to the group, that is, when the word is `start` send to the group, it will delete the bot stickers that are sent after the group `start`.

My code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters
import re                                                                                                                          


def delete_method(bot, update):
    mlist=['/start']  
    for i in mlist:
        if re.match(i, update, message.text):
            update.message.delete()


def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_method))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# for exit
# updater.idle()
```

But the bot does not work, that is, after sending the word `start` of the send to the group, it does not delete the stickers that are sent to the group.

The codes do not give any errors.And the group is a super group, and the bot is admin and it has access to messages!

What do you think is the problem ???

Comment: Is the bot group administrator?

Comment: @Ali Hashemi the bot admin in the group.

Answer (score 0):

This line here `if re.match(i, update, message.text):` is the problem. You are searching for `i` (which has the value `/start`) in the `update` object. I don't see why this should work.

You need to check if the current message is a sticker. If the message is a sticker, then `update.effective_message.sticker` will return a value. Otherwise it will return `None`. So you could check for a sticker with this i guess - i didn't test it:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters


def delete_sticker(bot, update):
    if update.effective_message.sticker:
        update.message.delete


if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_sticker))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```